# How do I pass a series of parameters into a TVF to get series of tables in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

In Postgres I have a query that uses a table value function

```
    SELECT 
 forecast.*
   FROM (
    SELECT
        generate_series(begin_date, end_date, '1 mon'::interval)::date zdate
) zdate
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL forecast_f(zdate.zdate)
    forecast(forecast_version , source, forecast_date, gl_date, customer, program, rev) ON true
where 1=1;
```

and forecast_f looks like:

```
A lot of boiler plate and then:
BEGIN
return query
select * from table where a lot of parameters are pulled in.
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in Bigquery and have googled around a few uncommon concepts:
Generating a series
passing parameters into a udf with the right data type (always an adventure)
tvf

and the documentation did not have a lot on TVF's  I thought maybe it can't handle tvfs and I'd have to join it all in to a column and split it somehow when it comes out of the function.  When I googled, others complained about special cases when TVF's don't work, but that would suggest there are cases where it does work, like maybe mine.  So I made this:

```
create or replace temp function snap(t timestamp)
as
(select * from forecast_stuff.forecast_full_practice where zfrom <= t and (zto> t or zto is null));
select * from snap(current_time())
```

which didn't work.  Also, this fancy number:

```
create or replace temp function snap(t timestamp)
as
((select intersection from forecast_stuff.forecast_full_practice where zfrom <= t and (zto> t or zto is null)));
select * from snap(current_time())
```

Didn't work either.  Something about if not exist not supported in temporary functions.  I remember doing something like this in f1 or dremel a few years back.  Did they not bring the technology forward?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the desired logic here. What's the goal of this function? Maybe we can find a way around, but first I'd like to see a question highlighting the goal.

Comment: The very basic question I have is if I have an scd2 fact table, how do I see the values changing over time.  In postgres, I use a tvf and a series generator.  As I think about it more, maybe BQ is so big I can just cross join the series to the fact table and then use the predicate to make the rows date specific.